# How long does it take for Google to change redirect uri

Tags: php, api, redirect, google-api

I have setup a redirect uri for a Google API, since I have changed the redirect uri I get an error response that the redirect uri is mismatched.

In the developer console I see the updated redirect uri but when I `var_dump` the Google Object I see for the property `redirect_uri` is still referring to the old one. So my question is, how long does it take before my changed redirect uri is active?

I cannot find anything in the docs. Is there anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Could you show us the code for the redirect, provide more details about it? There are many ways to redirect.

Comment: it may take upto 15 minutes, but did you change that  redirect_uri with your code?

Comment: @yash, I have setup a localhost and I have changed the redirect_uri in the developer console.

Comment: did you download the `client_secret.json` ? if not, then downlaod and add into project and change API code with your client_secret, client_id and redirect_uri?

Comment: I do have the client_secret.json downloaded, you're suggesting to redownload it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below link, which gives you basic introduction about configuration. 
[google api setup for php](http://enarion.net/programming/php/google-client-api/google-client-api-php/)

and if you change your redirect_uri, redownlaod `client_Secret.json` after 15 minutes. 
hope this may work for you.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I had to change the redirect_uri in the client_secret.json file.

Comment: yup. or have to replace file